# Snap Scroll not working while using infinite scrolling

Tags: html, css, django-templates, infinite-scroll

Attempting to snap to each container in an infinite scroll.

Unfortunately, I don't really know what I'm missing on this one - played around with quite a number of div setups and no luck.

Initial thoughts were that the scroll-snap-type parameter needs to be in the div the scroll comes from but I've tried moving this through the divs and haven't been able to get it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**from CSS**

```
.snap-container {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.child {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

**From HTML**

```
<div class="infinite-container">
  <div class="snap-container">
  {% for post in feed %}
    <div class="infinite-item">
      <div class="child">
      <div class="scrolling-wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="content-section">
              <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ post.creator.image.url }}">
              <div class="media-body">
                <a class="account-heading" href='/profile/{{ post.creator.pk }}'>{{ post.creator.user.username }}</a>
<div class="video-container">
                <video src="{{ post.highlight.highlight.url }}" type='video/mp4' controls data-id="{{ post.pk }}" width="1920" height="1080">
                  Program is incompatable with your browser, please update it.
                </video>
```